# Crosstab across 4 columns and multi-index output

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my data -

```
import pandas as pd
a = [[1,0,1,1], [1,1,0,0], [1,1,1,1], [1,1,1,1], [0,0,1,0], [0,1,0,0], [0,0,0,0], [1,0,0,1], [1,0,0,1], [0,1,0,1]]
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['A','B','C','D'])

   A  B  C  D
0  1  0  1  1
1  1  1  0  0
2  1  1  1  1
3  1  1  1  1
4  0  0  1  0
5  0  1  0  0
6  0  0  0  0
7  1  0  0  1
8  1  0  0  1
9  0  1  0  1
```

The desired output is a cross tab of counts between different combinations of the 4 columns and two values -

```
iterables = [["A", "B", "C", "D"], [1, 0]]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables)

op = [[0,0,3,3,3,3,0,0], [0,0,2,2,1,3,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0,3,1], 
      [0,0,0,0,0,0,3,3], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]

print(pd.DataFrame(op, index=index, columns=index))

     A     B     C     D   
     1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0
A 1  0  0  3  3  3  3  0  0
  0  0  0  2  2  1  3  0  0
B 1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  3  1
C 1  0  0  0  0  0  0  3  3
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
D 1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

I have tried `pd.crosstab()` and only seems to support two columns, not sure. Also tried pivot tables without luck. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count the occurrences of each values in each index, then use matrix multiplication:

```
tmp = (df.rename_axis(columns='c', index='i')
         .stack().to_frame(name='v')
         .reset_index()
         .groupby(['c','v'])['i'].value_counts()
         .unstack('i', fill_value=0)
      )

tmp @ tmp.T
```

Output:

```
c    A     B     C     D   
v    0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1
c v                        
A 0  4  0  2  2  3  1  3  1
  1  0  6  3  3  3  3  1  5
B 0  2  3  5  0  3  2  2  3
  1  2  3  0  5  3  2  2  3
C 0  3  3  3  3  6  0  3  3
  1  1  3  2  2  0  4  1  3
D 0  3  1  2  2  3  1  4  0
  1  1  5  3  3  3  3  0  6
```

Comment: accepting this as this runs faster than the previous answer. @quang for further context, you can add the time complexities - 

`1.82 ms ± 24.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)` --> this answer

`8.7 ms ± 71.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)` --> @mozway's answer

Answer (score 0):

You can first compute a long DataFrame, then the `crosstab`:

```
from itertools import product

tmp = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'col': a,
                               'idx': b,
                               'valc': df[a],
                               'vali': df[b]
                              })
                 for a, b in product(df, repeat=2)]
                )

out = pd.crosstab([tmp['idx'], tmp['vali']], [tmp['col'], tmp['valc']])
```

*NB. as the output is symmetric, you can also compute the combinations instead of the product.*

Output:

```
col       A     B     C     D   
valc      0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1
idx vali                        
A   0     4  0  2  2  3  1  3  1
    1     0  6  3  3  3  3  1  5
B   0     2  3  5  0  3  2  2  3
    1     2  3  0  5  3  2  2  3
C   0     3  3  3  3  6  0  3  3
    1     1  3  2  2  0  4  1  3
D   0     3  1  2  2  3  1  4  0
    1     1  5  3  3  3  3  0  6
```